# Add Keras Layer to Flatten input by a given axis

Tags: keras

If my last Keras Layer X outputs a tensor which looks, e.g. like this:

```
{
  {4, [22, 16,  11, 33], 24},
  {4, [12, 33,  87, 17], 14},
  {3, [92, 407, 25, 27], 34}
}
```

How can I add one more Layer Y that converts the output of X to this:

```
{
  {4, 22, 16,  11, 33, 24},
  {4, 12, 33,  87, 17, 14},
  {3, 92, 407, 25, 27, 34}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a type of layer called Flatten that suits your need (Keras core layer documentation [here](https://keras.io/layers/core/)):

```
from keras.layers import Flatten

# if you are using sequential model
...
model.add(Flatten())
...

# if you are using Model api
...
Y = Flatten()(X)
...
```

Comment: You mean I could Flatten the whole output and then use Reshape layer to transform the flattened tensor to (-1, 6)?